# Is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=c$ true?

Tags: limits

*Cantor Theorem* said that given $2$ range $\{a_n\},\ \{b_n\}$ so that $\displaystyle \left\{\begin{matrix}
 \forall n\in \mathbb N, a_n\le b_n\,, \left[a_{n+1}\,\,, b_{n+1}\,\right] \subset [a_n\,,b_n]\\
 \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(b_n-a_n\right)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$.

In this case there exists the only real number $c\in \left[a_n\,,b_n\,\right],\forall\, n$

> I wonder if I can say that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=c$.

Comment: This is Cantor's Intersection Theorem with respect to existence plus uniqueness. Then use monotonicity of the sequences to prove the limits exist and are equal. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem

Answer (score 3):

You can not only **say** that, you can even **prove** that.

To prove it, I advise you to:

1. Prove that the two sequences **have** a limit (they are bounded and monotonous)
2. Prove that the two limits are equal
3. Prove that the two limits are equal to $c$.